# I want overlay on image css

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, overlay, opacity

I want unclickable overlay on the top of the image

> codepen link on the comment section

html:

```
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" />
```

css:

```
img{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 1000;

}
```

with grey opacity on the top of the image

something like this
https://prnt.sc/10pm4zm

Comment: https://codepen.io/ranjan-raj-shrestha/pen/yLVdjLx

Comment: change `cursor:not-allowed;` to `pointer-events:none;`

Comment: with grey opacity on the top of the image something like this https://prnt.sc/10pm4zm

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" />
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

And css to be

```
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  }
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am still in problem . The container is still clickable and unclickable icon in not showing up https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkYpY.png . Here is the code on the codepen https://codepen.io/ranjan-raj-shrestha/pen/yLVdjLx#_=_

Comment: see the edited code. Move the `pointer-events` to `.container`

Answer (score 0):

You can add another div after the  tag. and give it the css as follows

```css
img{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  

}
div{
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:30px;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" />
<div></div>
```

Furthermore you can adjust opacity and the size of the overlay unclickable div accordingly

Comment: Thank you for the answer can you help me to fill the buttom div cover the image https://codepen.io/ranjan-raj-shrestha/pen/yLVdjLx

Comment: please clearify, you want the bottom div to overlay or cover your image?

Comment: well, remove the <div> tag. then the bottom <p> tag will cover the image

Comment: According to the source code given in: codepen.io/ranjan-raj-shrestha/pen/yLVdjLx the solution works. you can send me the code for  prnt.sc/10po9jx so i can check that out